# AntNet simulation in NS2

Tags: c++, tcl, ns2

So i'm trying to run ACO-based protocol "AntNet" on ns-2.34 and i'm currently getting this error when i try running an antnet tcl script via the command ns antnet.tcl .Can anybody help? Here's the error i get:

```
--- Classfier::no-slot{} default handler (tcl/lib/ns-lib.tcl) ---
_o21: no target for slot 4294967295
_o21 type: Classifier/Hash/Dest
content dump:
classifier _o21
0 offset
0 shift
2147483647 mask
1 slots
slot 3: _o401 (Classifier/Port)
-1 default
---------- Finished standard no-slot{} default handler ----------
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

---

The mentioned error from antnet.tcl appears on any 'Linux OS' .
So far we found no Solution.

→ http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/antnet/

→ → http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/problem-running-an-antnet-tcl-script-4175539390/

---

... The suggestion is to use Anthocnet.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ns-users/anthocnet|sort:date/ns-users/5zo35GmF4ds/osfCeA6x6dcJ

→ anthocnet_ns234.patch.gz
→  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNTTNVU1p4N1Exbnc/view?usp=sharing
Excatly → →
$ svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/anthocnet/code/ anthocnet-code
.....  except for the two .jar files
ns-2.34/anthocnet/tcl/libs/{ anthocnet-tcl-1.0.jar, commons-io-2.1.jar }.

`jar´s https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNNy1Edm9JSHBuY0k/view?usp=sharing

anthocnet_ns235.patch : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNOXN1T1V2a1pPYjg/view?usp=sharing

---